# scalar deleting destructor crashes

Tags: c++, windows, c++11

I am writing a little C++ program related to HTTP, but it always crashes, I attached WinDbg to it, and the stack is as below(I omitted the `RetAddr` and other irrelevant columns):

```
MSVCR120D!operator delete+0xa0 [f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp @ 52]
xproxy!HttpRequestInitial::`scalar deleting destructor'+0x53
xproxy!<lambda_e1d25e8e9bf0ff4ef442e9ed8e6e27a0>::operator()+0x7c [d:\xproxy\http_container.h @ 61]
xproxy!std::_For_each<HttpObject * __ptr64 * __ptr64,<lambda_e1d25e8e9bf0ff4ef442e9ed8e6e27a0> >+0x56 [d:\sdts\vs2013\vc\include\algorithm @ 24]
xproxy!std::for_each<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<HttpObject * __ptr64> > >,<lambda_e1d25e8e9bf0ff4ef442e9ed8e6e27a0> >+0x15e [d:\sdts\vs2013\vc\include\algorithm @ 35]
xproxy!HttpContainer::reset+0x8e [d:\xproxy\http_container.h @ 62]
```

The code will call `HttpContainer::reset()`, this function will delete all objects it stored, so the destructor of these objects will be called, and the delete operation causes the crash, but I have carefully checked my code, I cannot find why it crashes, since destructor of `HttpRequestInitial` does nothing, and also its parent classes.

The related code is as below:

```
class HttpContainer {
public:
    virtual ~HttpContainer() {
        for(auto it = objects_.begin(); it != objects_.end(); ++it)
            if(*it) delete *it;
    }

    virtual void reset() {
        std::for_each(objects_.begin(), objects_.end(),
                      [](HttpObject* object) { if(object) delete object; });
        objects_.clear();
    }

    // ...

private:
    std::vector<HttpObject*> objects_;
};

// HttpRequestInitial inherits from HttpInitial
// HttpInitial inherits from HttpObject
class HttpRequestInitial : public HttpInitial {
public:
    HttpRequestInitial() : HttpInitial(kHttpRequestInitial) {}

    virtual ~HttpRequestInitial() {}

    // ...

private:
    std::string method_;
    std::string uri_;
};
```

I can only find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948339/why-is-a-scalar-deleting-destructor-being-called-as-a-result-of-vector-delete-on) on SO similar to mine, but its answer says it is a compiler bug, but my compiler is VS2013, and I am not using an array but a vector. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your quick update. Yeah, I admit that I should use smart pointer instead, but now I am curious "the why". The object is dynamically allocated and inserted into the instance of `HttpContainer`, by using a `AppendObject(HttpObject *)` method I omitted, and it happens in the exe file(a class called `Session`), and not from a dll, the code is as below:

```
void Session::OnClientDataReceived(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
    HttpObject *object = new HttpRequestInitial();
    //... set its property here
    request_->AppendObject(object);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a sure-fire way to get yourself a Rule of Three violation. Why do you use raw pointers at all?

Comment: so you need to store the raw pointers? if you use smart pointers or just store the objects then you don't need a destructor at all

Comment: Read about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: That answer is wrong. I mean, it talks about a problem that _does_ exist, but it's the wrong problem for the question.

Comment: You need to show how the objects are allocated/constructed, and how they're being inserted into `objects`. Also, note that you do not need to do a NULL check before calling `delete`; it does that for you (passing a NULL pointer to `delete` does nothing and is safe).

Comment: Is `~HttpObject` destructor declared virtual? Are `HttpContainer` instances ever copied? You mention a DLL: which parts of the code you've shown reside in a DLL, and which parts in an EXE? Which runtime(s) are the two linked against?

Comment: Pay attention to the Rule of Three comments.  If you copy HttpContainer anywhere, your sure to get this kind of behavior because the default copy ctor is going to perform a member-wise copy resulting in two vectors that contain the same pointers.  Also, you don't need to check your pointers before calling delete.  It is safe to call delete on NULL.  Also, you are duplicating functionality in your destructor and reset() functions in different ways.  Better to call reset() in your destructor.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, all the related destructor are virtual, no HttpContainer instance copied, though I did not define copy constructor and copy assignment operator. I mention a DLL to emphasize that all related code is in the EXE file, the code reside in a DLL is SSL related, I believe it has nothing to do with the crash here.

Comment: @sbaker Thanks for pointing out the problems in my code.

Comment: Declare a copy constructor and copy assignment operator for `HttpContainer` as private and leave them unimplemented. If, as you say, it's indeed never copied, then the program would still build. If you start getting compiler errors, you would know exactly where your assumptions are violated.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have did that, make the class inherit from `private boost::noncopyable`, and there is no compilation error.